# Most efficient data structure for searching for a word in text Java

Tags: java, search, hashmap

I have a program which reads in a document and searches each page for a given search word. It then returns which pages the word appears in.

i.e. the word "brilliant" appears in the following pages: 1,4,6,8

At the moment I split the file into pages and store this into an ArrayList.
Each element of the ArrayList contains one page of the document

I then split each word on the page and store it into a hashMap, with the KEY being the position in the text this word appears in (i need to know this for other functionality) and the value being the word. I then search through the HashMap using;

```
if (map.containsValue(searchString) == true)
                return true;
             else
                 return false;
```

I do this for each PAGE.

Everything is working but I was wondering if there is a more efficient data structure I can use which stores all the words on a given page as well as the position on the page it appears?(since searching through the values in a map without giving a key is 0(n)).

I need to be able to search through this structure and find a word. Remember I also need the position for later use.

The code that i use to populate the map with the positions of the word in the text is;

```
    // text is the page of text from a document as a string
int key = 1; // position of the word in the text
    for (String element : text.split(" "))
            {
                map.put(key, element);
                key++;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a single `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Position>>` that maps the words to the occurrences? Each word of the text would be a key in the map, the page number and position would form the entry list.

Insertion is slightly tricky because of the list value:

```
ArrayList<Position> positions = words.get(word);
if (positions == null) {
  positions = new ArrayList<Position>();
  words.put(word, positions);
}
positions.add(position);
```

Alernatively, you could use a Guava Multimap: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html (In particular if you are using Guava for other purposes already -- I'd probably avoid pulling in a library dependency just for this)

**Edit**: Changed Integer to Position (and the set to a list), had overlooked that the exact position is required. Position should be similar to

```
class Position {
  int page;
  int index; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Are you saying store the document in a hashMap with string being the text on each page and Set<Integer> being the page number?

Comment: The string would be individual words, the integer set would contain the page numbers this word occurs on (I have tried to clarify this in the answer text)

Comment: but in order to compute the page numbers the word occurs on i'd need to  use a similar algorithm as In my original post, which would take 0(n). I was hoping to avoid that and use something more efficient if possible

Comment: @Steve you do O(n) everytime you search the document, not once for a document. That is huge difference.

Comment: For extensibility, that should be a `Map<String, ? extends Set<Integer>>`.

Comment: Where are the positions of the words stored in this solution?

Comment: Good idea—this is an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) and is suitable for the task.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: oops, fixed.

Comment: @WChargin: Unless the data structure is exposed to the outside, I'd keep it as specific as possible.

Comment: It's not getting any better though. Now you would have to loop through all the positions if you just want to get the page numbers.

Comment: I need the positions for functionality later on in the software. I need to retrieve the word before and after each search word

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I guess it depends on the application whether this is an issue. If it is, one could use nested maps or two parallel maps instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) or something from [Guava collections](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) myself, but barring that I think the most efficient structure would be:

```
HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>> words;

        ^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^
         word            page            position
```

Using `words.get("brilliant").keySet();` would immediately give you all the pages that "brilliant" appears on. That's `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)` if I'm not mistaken.

After reading in the comments that you will also need to retrieve the word before and after each search words, I think you'll need a second data structure for that lookup:

```
TreeSet<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, String>> positions;

        ^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
         page            position  word
```

Or alternatively, using the respective indexes of the two lists for page and position:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> positions;
```